# Shortest way to do this Python 3 list operation in PHP, JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, python, list, python-3.x

I am learning Python and I just read in a book that Python 3 lets you do this cool list operation:

```
first, *middle, last = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

first: `1`
middle: `[2, 3, 4]`
last: `5`

This is great if I want to **iterate through the middle of the list, and do separate things with the first and last items**.

What's the easiest (read: most sugary) way to do this in Python 2.x, PHP, and JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Python2, you can just use slice notation, also it's easier to read I think.

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> a, b, c = t[0], t[1:-1], t[-1]
>>> a, b, c
(1, (2, 3, 4), 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

python 2.x

```
first, middle, last = a[0], a[1:-1], a[-1]
```

Comment: Since this is about succinctness, you would have to include the additional assignment required here (`a = [1,2,3,4,5]`). Otherwise, if you want to do this on a literal in practice, you would have to spell out the literal three times.

Comment: Well, this doesn't make much sense with a literal. why not simply `first, middle, last = 1, [2, 3, 4], 5`..

Comment: @yi_H: I am not sure if I am right to do so, but I consider list-comprehensions to be list-literals.

Answer (score 2):

A solution in PHP could be the following, using [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) and [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop):

```
$first = array_shift($arr);
$last = array_pop($arr);
$middle = $arr;
```

Comment: It will be just slightly more efficient to do the pop first, of course.  ;)

Comment: Just for the record in JavaScript it works as well (`arr.shift()` and `arr.pop()`).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
list($first, $middle, $last) = array($array[0], array_splice($array, 1, -1), $array[1]);
```

It destroys the original array though, leaving only the first and last elements.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2:

```
first, middle, last = a[0], a[1:-1], a[-1]
```

### PHP:

```
$first = array_shift($arr);
$last = array_pop($arr);
$middle = $arr;
```

### JavaScript:

```
var a = Array.apply(0,myAry), first = a.shift(), last = a.pop(), middle = a;
```

For the JavaScript sample, I created a copy of the array so as not to destroy the original.